# Should the coroutine result object ever be constructed after initial_suspend()?

Tags: c++, coroutine, c++20, compiler-bug, c++-coroutine

I've been writing a coroutine library, and I've run into a peculiar problem. In some cases, the construction of the coroutine result object was sequenced *after* the call to `initial_suspend`.

**Question: is this sequencing a bug on the part of the compiler?**

## Background

In my particular case, this was causing a crash, as a generator promise executed under the assumption that it had no owner.

The relevant section of the C++20 standard is section 9.5.4.7, which states:

> The expression `promise.get_return_object()` is used to initialize the glvalue result or prvalue result object of a call to a coroutine. The call to `get_return_object` is sequenced before the call to `initial_suspend` and is invoked at most once.

When I read this portion of the standard, I originally interpreted it to mean that the initialization of the coroutine's result object is sequenced immediately after the call to `promise.get_return_object()`: when you initialize something, initialization occurs immediately after the computation of the arguments to the constructor, and not as a delayed effect.

Unfortunately, this is not the behavior I observed. **The source of the crash is that the initialization of the result object was sequenced after the initial suspend**, despite the call to `promise.get_return_object()` being sequenced before the initial suspend.

## Observing this behavior in code ([view live example here](https://godbolt.org/z/cEzr9d))

Let's write a very simple type that can be returned from a coroutine:

```cpp
template <class Promise>
struct coroutine {
    std::coroutine_handle<Promise> handle;
    using promise_type = Promise;
    coroutine(std::coroutine_handle<Promise> p) : handle(p) {
        std::cout << "  Running coroutine(std::coroutine_handle<Promise> p)\n";
    }

    ~coroutine() {
        if (handle) {
            handle.destroy();
        }
    }
};
```

Because `coroutine<Promise>` can be constructed from a `std::coroutine_handle<Promise>`, the call to `promise.get_return_object()` can return either a `std::coroutine_handle<Promise>` which is used to construct the `coroutine`, or it can return a
`coroutine<Promise>` directly.

Let's write two different promise types, one for each option:

```cpp
struct promise_base {
    std::suspend_never initial_suspend() {
        std::cout << "  Running initial_suspend()\n";
        return {};
    }
    std::suspend_always final_suspend() { return {}; }
    void return_void() {}
    void unhandled_exception() { std::terminate(); }
};

struct promise_A : promise_base {
    using handle = std::coroutine_handle<promise_A>;
    handle get_return_object() {
        std::cout << "  Running get_return_object()\n";
        return handle::from_promise(*this);
    }
};
struct promise_B : promise_base {
    using handle = std::coroutine_handle<promise_B>;
    coroutine<promise_B> get_return_object() {
        std::cout << "  Running get_return_object()\n";
        return {handle::from_promise(*this)};
    }
};
```

We can then write two identical coroutines based on `promise_A` and `promise_B`:

```cpp
coroutine<promise_A> run_A() {
    std::cout << "Inside coroutine body\n";
    co_return;
}
coroutine<promise_B> run_B() {
    std::cout << "Inside coroutine body\n";
    co_return;
}
```

In this code,

- `promise_A` returns a handle from `get_return_object`, and this is used to construct a result object of type `coroutine<promise_A>`.
- `promise_B` directly returns a `coroutine<promise_B>`, which is returned as the result object.

**In the case of `promise_A`, the construction of the `coroutine<promise_A>` result object is sequenced *after* the call to initial_suspend().**

We can write the following test code to verify this:

```
void test_promise_A() {
    std::cout << "------ Testing A ------\n";
    run_A();
    std::cout << "\n\n";
}
void test_promise_B() {
    std::cout << "------ Testing B ------\n";
    run_B();
    std::cout << "\n\n";
}
int main() {
    test_promise_A();
    test_promise_B();
}
```

Under GCC 10.1, this produces the following output. Note the difference in sequencing between `Testing A` and `Testing B`.

```
------ Testing A ------
  Running get_return_object()
  Running initial_suspend()
Inside coroutine body
  Running coroutine(std::coroutine_handle<Promise> p)


------ Testing B ------
  Running get_return_object()
  Running coroutine(std::coroutine_handle<Promise> p)
  Running initial_suspend()
Inside coroutine body
```

To reiterate the question: **Is the sequencing of `Testing A` a bug?**

Comment: You answered your own question. This is the call to get_return_object that is sequenced before initial suspenced. So initialization of the return object is unsequenced with initial_suspend, and if your code validity depend on a sequencement between that two points, you get UB.

Comment: The fix for this bug was very simple, but I still find that frustrating. I really don’t like things being unsequenced